# CZC power steering

Tags: steering, power, colt

Trying to get the 2 little clips off the rear of the circuit board of the EPS pump on my CZC colt to disassemble it all , any ideas how they come off

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! An image of what you're trying to remove would tell a 1000 words :o) Any way you could help us out here and show us what you're talking about?

Comment: Presumably you don't mean 'pump', isn't the power steering fully electric on the Colt?